# customize slider image into link in slick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

so I've found a slick slider which is perfect for my situation and I'm trying to create a slider which each content or picture acts as a link when it clicked

I already tried to change the image into `href` and the layout just doesn't work out.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }
    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }
    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: .2;
    }

    .slick-active {
      opacity: .5;
    }
    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
```

I hope this code helps, and if it isn't clear I'll try to provide you the information you need.

Comment: Do u want all images are link?

Comment: you have a large number of slides to show, its reason why images are so small...links don't break you logic. You set 5 images to show with center mode and you have 7 images inside 500 pixels container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it would be a bit of a pain but could you do this using jQuerys `.click()` function?

Give each image a unique class and go from there?

**OR**

Have you tried wrapping the div in an a element? You could then make the A into a block element with css targeting just those?

```
<a href="#">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: my god why didn't I think of this, thanks so much it works perfectly

Comment: Haha sometimes when your so stuck in an issue it's hard to think of things you would think are really simple / easy!! Glad it worked though!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the selector for the wrapper in the slick options. You just need to adjust your html. So instead of `div` use `a`.

html

```
<section class="center slider">
    <a href="#1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </a>
    <a href="#2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </a>
    <a href="#3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </a>
    <a href="#4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </a>
    <a href="#5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </a>
    <a href="#6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </a>
    <a href="#7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </a>
    <a href="#8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </a>
    <a href="#9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </a>
  </section>
```

js

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $(".center").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    slide: 'a' // your selector
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping them in a div container and then adding markup for `<a href="something"><img src="something"/></a>`, we can directly make the containing anchor tag is wrapper and replace `<div>` by `<a href="anywhere you want to link your slide"><img></a>.` 
No extra styles of JS. It solved for me.